# A single "nav.php" for homepage and subfolders

Tags: php, html

I've been trying to improve the efficiency of my sites by having a php file for the navigation, footer, sidebar etc. However the way i'm currently doing it requires two files. One specifically for the homepage and another for the other pages in their respective folders.

I.E. 
navhome.php is like this:

```
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a  href="pickup/">Pickup Route</a></li>
```

and then i have a seprate file for the rest of the pages

```
<li><a href="../index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a  href="../pickup/">Pickup Route</a></li>
```

What i want to do is make it easier and cleaner and merge these into one file. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an absolute path to your pages:

```
<li><a href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/pickup/">Pickup Route</a></li>
```

The `/` indicates "from the root web directory". No matter where you are in the website the browser will request the page relative to the root web directory.

Comment: Wow, actually really simple. Thanks